# Leak_DefinitelyLost can valgrind points out where is the last time the address was on the stack?

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm having a leak which is very hard to detect;
Can valgrind  tell me which is the last call where address was accessible? and what were the values of the variables? I use Clion, can it just break when it happens?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "instantaneous" detection of leaks functionality in valgrind/memcheck
that reports a leak exactly at the time the last pointer to a block is lost.

There was an experimental tool that tried to do that, but it was never considered for integration in valgrind, due to various difficulties to make this work properly.

If your leak is easy to reproduce, you can run your application under valgrind +
gdb/vgdb.  You can then add breaks at various points in your program, and then
use monitor commands such as "leak_check" or "who_points_at" to check if the leak already happened.  By refining the locations where to put a break, this might help to find when the last pointer to a block is lost.

See e.g. https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands for more info.